# How can I drop multiple tables (but not all) in one database?

Tags: database, sql-server-2012

My case is : DBname : Groups, and temp tables created by a serial number each time the backend user creates a new group of glossary items (i.e. 1000, 10001, 10002...) How can I drop tables which have a serial number > 10002 ?

What I need is to drop the tables using the condition where the table name > 1002.

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server. Please inform what RDBMS are you using ?

Comment: You will probably need dynamic SQL to do this, regardless of your database version.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Updated , thanks for the advice :)

Answer (score 1):

In Sql Server the simplest way would probably be to generate dynamic sql using `information_schema.tables`:

```
DECLARE @Sql nvarchar(4000) = ''; -- you might need max instead of 4000 here...

 SELECT @Sql = @Sql + 'DROP TABLE '+ TABLE_NAME +';'
 FROM information_schema.tables
 WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'glossary_items%'
 AND CAST(REPLACE(TABLE_NAME, 'glossary_items_', '') As int) > 1002;

EXEC(@Sql)
```

Assuming table names are `glossary_items_XXXX` where `XXXX` is the number
(so `glossary_items_1000`, `glossary_items_1001` etc')

Following Dan Guzman's comment - a better implementation would be using `for xml` for 2016 version (or earlier):

```
SET @Sql = (
    SELECT 'DROP TABLE '+ TABLE_NAME +';'
    FROM information_schema.tables
    WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'glossary_items%'
    AND CAST(REPLACE(TABLE_NAME, 'glossary_items_', '') As int) > 1002;
    FOR XML PATH('')
)
```

or `string_agg` for 2017 version (or later):

```
SELECT @Sql = STRING_AGG('DROP TABLE '+ TABLE_NAME, ';')
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'glossary_items%'
AND CAST(REPLACE(TABLE_NAME, 'glossary_items_', '') As int) > 1002;
```

Comment: Method is the right idea, but the question asked about dropping the table, not deleting the rows.  (he may have edited the question).

Comment: @StuartAinsworth thanks! this was requested from the first version of the question, It was just a simple mistake by me. good catch!

Comment: Although this method might work, the behavior of aggregate string concatenation (`@SQL = @SQL + ...`) is undefined with the behavior being dependent on the execution plan. It would be best to use `STRING_AGG` (SQL 2017+) or `XML PATH` (SQL 2016 and earlier).